# DotNetOpenAuth or any other .Net Open ID library for .net 2.0 projects

Tags: c#, .net, .net-2.0, openid, dotnetopenauth

I want to use DotNetOpenAuth library for implementing OpenId Login in my web application. The web Application is being built in C# for .NET 2.0, and I am not able to find any .NET Library compatible for .NET 2.0 project.

When I try to add the DotNetOpenAuth .dll, it shows error telling its dependency on .NET 3.5 libraries.

Please help!! I have exhausted myself researching for it.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3997172/oauth-2-0-service-provider-net-libraries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DotNetOpenAuth v3.x is strictly for .NET 3.5 and above.

Please check out [DotNetOpenId v2.x](http://teamcity.dotnetopenauth.net/repository/download/bt14/1366%3aid/DotNetOpenId-2.5.8.10214.zip) for .NET 2.0 support.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few other .NET OAuth libs you could take a look at if you have no luck with DotNetOpenAuth.

Check out the *DotNet* section at http://oauth.net/code/